# How many times would you say that "quite a couple of times" are?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He's been here quite a couple of times.

1. Would this be a natural thing to say?
2. How many times would you say that "quite a couple of times" are? (I know there's no precise answer to it)

Comment: It's more "quite" I was unsure of. What it does to the statement.

Comment: Where did this sentence come from?

Comment: It comes from me.

Comment: "Quite a couple" is not idiomatic to my ears the way "quite a few" is. The "quite" adds no additional meaning (other than a bit of confusion!) to the sentence.

Comment: Not in American English, it's not. I have no idea, but if I had to guess I'd think it was *often*.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is not natural.
2. I would assume the person saying this meant "many" and as a non-native English speaker was misusing an idiom they had heard (e.g. "quite a few").